# Firebase crashlytics dashboard keeps Loading

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, crashlytics

Firebase crashlytics console displays "loading" after a click on the "Enable Crashlytics" button.

1. Firebase Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/
2. Select Project
3. Select Crashlytics
4. Click "Enable Crashlytics"

It displays the spinner. It has been like this for several minutes.

Comment: Make sure you have this in your info.plist : <key>FirebaseCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED</key>
<true/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure that you've followed all the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android) to get the Crashlytics SDK set up. Then, [force a crash](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android) to test your implementation. This is required to get past the onboarding screen that you're seeing at the moment.

If that doesn't work, try [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#enable_debug_logging) and going through the build, run, crash, and relaunch process again, and paste any Crashlytics or Firebase-related logs into your original question.

Comment: I can't able to see the crash reports in firebase crashlytics for release. But I can able to see the fatal errors from dev

Comment: Also getting Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.2

Comment: Hi Sejn, please open up a new question on this issue and more details on how you've implemented these SDKs. `Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.2` doesn't look related to Crashlytics.

Comment: did you fix it @sejn ?

Comment: downgrading to version 8 helped me
@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "8.3.0",